# How does HAProxy handles connection forwarding

Tags: haproxy

I'm planning to use HAProxy to achieve stickyness to route same destination URL to backend Proxy server.
So i want to know if HAProxy disassembles the HTTP/HTTPS requests, builds them back again and forwards to any of the backend that is configured?

In other words, is it possible that i can use HSProxy to just forward the incoming connection to any of the backend without disassembly or assembly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Short: Yes you can.

Longer answer:
HAProxy have two main modes "http" and "tcp". You can use the tcp mode to just forward the request from the clients to backend servers. You can also use http mode to manipulate the http request if you want. HAPRoxy can also terminates TLS and talk to the backends via TLS.